# PHP run query once

Tags: php, mysqli

This may sound silly but i am trying to figure out the best approach to run a query only once in a stats table that have all values set to 0 as a starting point and i would like your opinion, my table is by example:

```
Col1 - Col2 - Col3 - Col4 - Created - Modified
0      0      0      0      Datetime- Datetime
```

My main script have several foreach loops where i evaluate some conditions, if there is a match, i build the query and run a mysqli multiquery at the end, by example (pseudo code):

```
$query = '';
foreach ($array as $val) {
  if ($val == $mycondition) {
    $query .= "UPDATE mytable SET Col1 = Col1 + 1;";   
  }
}

$db = mysqliConnection();
$num = $db->query("SELECT * FROM my table WHERE id = '".$ID."' AND Col1 = 0 AND Col2 = 0 AND Col3 = 0 AND Col4 = 0");

$result = mysqli_num_rows($num);
// if 0 it means that nothing has been modified yet so i can run the query
if ($result > 0) {
  $db->multi_query($query)
}
$db->close();
```

This is the best approach i can think of right now, i created the columns created and modified but i think they will not work for this, as the creation time will always be before the modified time, probably in milisecs (but i dont want to risk taking the path to allow the mutiquery run after max 3 sec or so, cause if the user run the page several time by mistake between 3 secs it will store wrong values) and the modified column will change as soon as the first value is updated making the next queries fail if i rely on that column as condition in the WHERE clause (even if are just milisec).

What do you think guys is the best approach or i am in the right path?

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe you could look in to using SessionId for your query rather than when it was accessed?  It is not self apparent what the update has to do with the select.  Perhaps you could expand on that for a better answer.

Comment: I couldn't quite catch the reason of separating the queries? Wouldn't attaching the WHERE clause from the Select query to Update query work for you?

Comment: Oh yes sorry it could be on the same query, i was sleepy lol thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a flag. Something like:

```
$queryFlag = 0;

if($queryFlag == 0) {
     //Do you things here
     $queryFlag = 1;
}
```

Comment: Hey good Idea! but stored in the db, so i can check if the flag is on or off on a given ID and if is off then run the update thaks